# Category of Chain Complexes over Chain Complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have a few questions.
Let A be an abelian category, and Ch(A) the category of chain complexes over A.
Now let $$Ch^2(A) = Ch(Ch(A)) $$ and inductively $$Ch^n(A) = Ch^{n-1}(Ch(A)) $$

1. Is there a "limit" category $Ch^{\infty}(A)$ when $n \to \infty $? is it an abelian category?
2. If D(A) denotes the derived category of A, does $$ D(Ch(A)) \cong Ch(D(A)) \ ?$$
3. If not, what is the relation, for every $n$, between $D(Ch^n(A))$ and $Ch^n(D(A))$.
4. The derived category D(A) of A is defined as a certain localization of $Ch(A)$. We can do the same process to $Ch^n(A)$ for every $n$. Let me call $$D^n(A) $$
   the category obtained in this way from $Ch^n(A)$. What are the properties of these categories? Does these categories have to do something with the usual derived category? How about $Ch^{\infty}(A)$? Can $D^\infty(A)$ be defined?

Comment: 1. There are several possible definitions. You have to choose how you embed $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathbf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$. 2. No.

Comment: The stalk at degree 0.